# Getting n pairs from a sequence of strings

Tags: javascript

Is there a method with javascript that can return `n` sequences of string that form a part of a larger string?

For example, in a sequence like:

```
Paris, Italy, London, Perth, Moscow, Wellington
```

How could I get `n` word-pairs where n = 2 in this example. The output would be:

```
Paris, Italy
London, Perth
Moscow, Wellington
```

Is there a built in method with Javascript that could help me achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression that matches non-space characters, followed by a comma and space, followed by more non-space characters (where the next character after the match is a comma or the end of the string):

```js
const input = 'Paris, Italy, London, Perth, Moscow, Wellington';
console.log(
  input.match(/\S+, \S+(?=,|$)/g)
);
```

For additional sequences of words, repeat the initial non-space characters followed by a comma and space, eg:

```js
const input = 'Paris, Italy, London, Perth, Moscow, Wellington';
console.log(
  input.match(/(?:\S+, ){2}\S+(?=,|$)/g)
);
```

The above matches 3 words. For 4 words, just change the `{2}` to `{3}`, and so on.

If you want a function, pass the number of words you need into `new RegExp`:

```js
const getPairs = (str, words) => {
  const pattern = new RegExp(String.raw`(?:\S+, ){${words - 1}}\S+(?=,|$)`, 'g');
  return str.match(pattern);
};

const input = 'Paris, Italy, London, Perth, Moscow, Wellington';
console.log(
  getPairs(input, 3)
);
```

Comment: What if I need 3 pair of words? For example, `Paris, Italy, London` as one and so on?

Comment: Just repeat the initial (non-space followed by space) part of the pattern as many times as you need

Comment: Okay. Is there also a way to make a dynamic regex. For example that can take numbers on the go, like `2` , `3`?

Comment: Create the pattern from `new RegExp`, substituting in the number of words to repeat (minus one)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by grouping them using a modulo, allowing you to get the relevant size of chunks:

```js
const input = 'Paris, Italy, London, Perth, Moscow, Wellington';

const groupBy = f => arr => arr.reduce((prev, curr, i) => {
  const key = f(curr, i);
  const hasKey = prev.hasOwnProperty(`${key}`);
  
  return {
    ...prev,
    [key]: [...(hasKey ? prev[key] : []), curr]
  }
}, {})

const grouper = size => (_, i) => i % size;

const splitIntoChunks = (chunkSize, arr) => Object.values(groupBy(grouper(arr.length / chunkSize))(arr))

console.dir(splitIntoChunks(2, input.split(', ')))
```